# How to implement a decision tree for the graph

Tags: python

[I was given a graph to write a function that implements a decision tree.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDDb8.png)
Can you give any hints or explain what libraries I should use or maybe share some useful links. I tried to go the dumb way and this is what I got. Apparently it wasn't accepted because the cyclomatic complexity was exceeded.

```
def main(x):
    if x[4] == 1996:
        if x[0] == 1987:
            if x[3] == 'GAMS':
                return 0 if x[2] == 2020 else 1
            elif x[3] == 'CLICK':
                return 2 if x[2] == 2020 else 3
            elif x[3] == 'FORTH':
                return 4
        elif x[0] == 1986:
            if x[2] == 2020:
                if x[1] == 'TLA':
                    return 5
                elif x[1] == 'COBOL':
                    return 6
                elif x[1] == 'ASP':
                    return 7
            if x[2] == 1995:
                return 8
    else:
        return 9 if x[2] == 2020 else 10
```

Function call:

```
x = main([1987, 'COBOL', 2020, 'CLICK', 1996])  # 2
y = main([1986, 'ASP', 2020, 'CLICK', 1996])  # 7
print(x, y)
```

output:

```
2 7
```

Comment: create a node class, have a root node, and then create a node structure (graph) which can be dynamic...

Comment: To hopefully add on the previous comment: I think that the whole point of the exercise is to understand the patterns in graphs and how they can be decomposed in reusable code pieces. Think that nodes either have a value (i.e., they are leaf nodes) or edges to child nodes. Hence, what do in each node is always the same, and following the graph is a recursive (or iterative) operation of following along the node structure starting from the root node ;)